# chocolatey doesnt install activeperl package correctly

Tags: perl, chocolatey

Using Windows Server 2012 R2, on AWS.

When I install activeperl, chocolatey completes it successfully.

```
C:\Users\valentin.kragelj>choco install activeperl
Chocolatey v1.2.1
Installing the following packages:
activeperl
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading ActivePerl 5.28... 100%

ActivePerl v5.28 [Approved]
activeperl package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.

The package ActivePerl wants to run 'ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[A]ll - yes to all/[N]o/[P]rint): y

Downloading ActivePerl 64 bit
  from 'https://cli-msi.s3.amazonaws.com/ActivePerl-5.28.msi'
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\valentin.kragelj\AppData\Local\T
emp\2\chocolatey\ActivePerl\5.28\ActivePerl-5.28.msi (5.52 MB).
Download of ActivePerl-5.28.msi (5.52 MB) completed.
Hashes match.
Installing ActivePerl...
ActivePerl has been installed.
  activeperl may be able to be automatically uninstalled.
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
 The install of activeperl was successful.
  Software installed as 'msi', install location is likely default.

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

C:\Users\valentin.kragelj>
```

However when I check `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin` there is no perl executable, and in `C:\Perl64` there is only one file - `perl.ico`.

I'm firts time chocolatey user. What can I do about activeperl not being properly installed?

Comment: I can't even install the package as it's a bit broken, so I can't test this. I have contacted the maintainers to let them know and will pick it up and fix it (if I can).

That doesn't really answer your question, but it gives you a hint it might be broken.

Assuming it's actually installed outside of `C:\Perl64` and the icon is just in that folder, did you try, as the message says: Close/reopen your shell to see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).

Comment: I used to have all sorts of problems with ActivePerl. Then I changed to Strawberry Perl, and things just work.

Comment: @pauby I think it should be C:\Perl64 folder. If I uninstall activeperl package, the folder is deleted, and created again, if I install it again.